# SVD with different solution as WolframAlpha

Tags: java, opencv

I've found out that the results of the SVDecomp function in Java are very different from the results of WolframAlpha.

The input matrix is excactly the same for OpenCV and WolframAlpha

```
{{0.2229632566816983, 18.15370964847313, 4.87085706173828},
{-14.31728552253419, 2.642676839378287, -33.69501515553716},
{-2.982323803144884, 33.70091859922499, 0.8997452211463326}}
```

Here are the results from WolframAlpha:

```
U = (-0.441818862735368 | 0.214800119324567 | -0.871009185525260
-0.245069575462508 | -0.962880608842737 | -0.113145200062862
-0.862981457340684 | 0.163468167704881 | 0.478059789601005)
W = (38.5925763913943 | 0 | 0
0 | 36.8337256561100 | 0
0 | 0 | 3.76859638821616×10^-10)
V = (0.155053443270976 | 0.362336795687042 | 0.919059560758203
-0.978207790691182 | 0.186347267503429 | 0.0915653543928191
0.138086740713550 | 0.913228745925823 | -0.383334461865688)
```

And here is what OpenCV produces when using SCDecomp:

```
 U: [0.4418188627353685, 0.2148001193245664, -0.8710091855252606;
0.2450695754625076, -0.9628806088427376, -0.113145200062862;
 0.8629814573406845, 0.1634681677048805, 0.4780597896010051]
 W: [38.59257639139431; 36.83372565611004; 3.768597946996713e-10]
 VT:[-0.155053443270976, 0.3623367956870423, 0.9190595607582029;
 0.9782077906911818, 0.1863472675034285, 0.09156535439281914;
-0.1380867407135498, 0.9132287459258235, -0.3833344618656882]
```

To mention: W in OpenCV is not a matrix, as well as the sign of the values are sometimes different.

Is this a bug? Here is my SourceCode

```
Core.SVDecomp(E, w, u, vt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the result are that different:

- Both **U** matrices contain the same vector with the 1st one (1st column of each matrix) being the opposite of the other (no problem here just a sign alteration)
- W is the same but in the first case is returned as diagonal matrix and in the second as vector (only the main diagonal is returned).
- The **V** matrices are the same case as the **U** ones (the first vector is the opposite).

So the results are the same.